# Performance problems on Ubuntu guest on VMWare player

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

I'm looking for some advice on how to troubleshoot performance problems.

Here's the situation:

- Windows Server 2008 host, Ubuntu 9.04 Server guest on VMWare Player 3.
- Host hardware is a Celeron 2GHz with 2GB RAM; Guest has 256MB RAM.
- The server is used as a LAMP testing server.  Installed is:

  - Apache with PHP
  - MySQL
  - SFTP
  - Samba
  - No GUI/DE
- As it is a testing server just for myself, it generally just has to handle single HTTP requests at a time.
- I'm relatively new to Linux

The server often takes 5secs+ to respond to requests.  Where can I start looking for the problem?

Edit: The host is not doing anything else at the moment, and CPU usage is low.

Edit2: I've upped the RAM to 512MB, and also tried running it on a different host - same result.

Comment: 2GB for W2K8, a hypervisor and a VM is cutting it close. Is this the first VM you've used on this machine or is it a new 'build'? Did you install the vmtools? have you tried running it with more/less memory assigned?

Comment: No, I've used this machine for other VMs before, including a Win2003 with SQL Server that had 768MB RAM, and performance was decent, if not spectacular.  According to Webmin this one is only using about 100MB of the 256, but I'll try adjusting.  VMWare tools is installed, yes.

Answer (score 0):

**256MB** of ram for the guest is **quite short**, but it highly depends on your web application.

It may be hard to spot (even using `free -m`) because PHP is only running for a few seconds, meaning it will take the memory he needs only for those seconds and then frees them up.

Try increasing the memory.

Comment: Upped RAM to 512MB (see edit above), with no improvement.